# Shinyapps.io publish issue: webshot dependent library "PhantomJS" missing

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

When I published my app to shinyapps.io, I came across the following issues:

- PhantomJS
- file(con, "rb"): cannot open the connection

The full log in the output pdf file:

```
PhantomJS not found. You can install it with webshot::install phantomjs(). If it is installed, please make sure the phantomjs executable can be found via the PATH variable.
Warning in normalizePath(f2): path[1]="./webshot6c3d201217.pdf": No such file or directory 
Warning in file(con, "rb"): cannot open file ’./webshot6c3d201217.pdf’: No such file or directory
 Error in file(con, "rb"): cannot open the connection
A tibble: 0 x 2
... with 2 variables: group <chr>, sort.order <dbl>
PhantomJS not found. You can install it with webshot::install phantomjs(). If it is installed, please make sure the phantomjs executable can be found via the PATH variable.
Warning in normalizePath(f2): path[1]="./webshot6c23dc44d3.pdf": No such file or directory
Warning in file(con, "rb"): cannot open file ’./webshot6c23dc44d3.pdf’: No such file or directory
Error in file(con, "rb"): cannot open the connection
```

I can create the PDF successfully after installing PhantomJS on my local Shiny server, however, I have no idea how to address it on shinyapps.io.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From RStudio:

"For any missing system dependencies for packages on shinyapps.io, we ask that you file an issue on our repository here: https://github.com/rstudio/shinyapps-package-dependencies clearly stating the dependency needed and the specific package you're trying to install. If this is urgent, we'd recommend filing a pull request following our steps here: https://github.com/rstudio/shinyapps-package-dependencies/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md"

My followup:

https://github.com/rstudio/shinyapps-package-dependencies/pull/180

Comment: From RStudio: You should be able to use webshot::install_phantomjs() which will install PhantomJS into a user writeable location directly from your Shiny application, and webshot:::find_phantom() to check if it is already there and skip installation.