# Downloading wordcloud2 output on shiny.io does not work

Tags: r, shiny, wordcloud2

I am trying to download the output from wordcloud2 on a shiny app hosted on shiny.io.

Previously, I had an issue with downloading wordcloud2 output on the browser and managed to solve it here [Downloading wordcloud2 output as png/jpg on shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54260164/downloading-wordcloud2-output-as-png-jpg-on-shiny/54287988#54287988).

For comparison and clarity sake I have shown similar download function which works for leaflet maps. The reason I included the leaflet map section because both the wordcloud 2 and leaflet maps outputs are html, thus I thought they would have the same behaviour.

The code below shows

```
 library(leaflet)
 library(htmlwidgets)
 library(webshot)
 library(shiny)
  library(wordcloud2)

      ui <- fluidPage(
           leafletOutput("map"),
            downloadLink("downloadMap", "Download1"),
            downloadLink("savemap", "Download2"), 
            wordcloud2Output("wordclH2020"),
            downloadLink( "savecloud", "DImage"),
            downloadLink( "saveword", "DImage2")
                  )

      server <- function(input,output) {
         ###### MAP SECTION ##############################
            mapReact <- reactive({
                    leaflet() %>%      
 addTiles('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.de/tiles/osmde/{z}/{x}/{y}.png') %>% 
     addCircles(12.5,42,radius=500) %>% addMarkers(12,42,popup="Rome")
      })

         output$map <- renderLeaflet({
                     mapReact()
                          })

     ##### map download 1 works on browser but not shiny.io ###########
        output$downloadMap <- downloadHandler(
                  filename = paste("LeafletMap", '.png', sep=''),
                  content = function(file) {
                  owd <- setwd(tempdir())
                  on.exit(setwd(owd))
              saveWidget(mapReact(), "temp.html", selfcontained = FALSE)
                webshot("temp.html", file = file, cliprect = "viewport")
                         })

        ##### map download 2 works on both browser and  shiny.io ###########
      output$savemap <- downloadHandler(
                filename = "map.html",
                content = function(file){
                saveWidget(
               widget = mapReact()
                , file = file
              )
               }
               )
 ############### WORD CLOUD SECTION ###############################
         wordcl <- reactive ({
            wordcloud2(demoFreq, color = "random-light", backgroundColor = "grey")  })

      output$wordclH2020 <- renderWordcloud2({  wordcl() })

   ##### wordcloud download 1 works on browser but not shiny.io ###########  
             output$savecloud <- downloadHandler(
                   filename = paste("LeafletMap", '.png', sep=''),
                   content = function(file) {
                  owd <- setwd(tempdir())
                  on.exit(setwd(owd))
               saveWidget(wordcl(), "temp.html", selfcontained = FALSE)
           webshot("temp.html", delay =15, file = file, cliprect = "viewport")

             })
  ##### wordcoud download 2 does not work on browser nor shiny.io ###########
    output$saveword <- downloadHandler(
             filename = "word.html",
              content = function(file){
              saveWidget(
              widget = wordcl()
                , file = file
                )
               }
               )

            }

      shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any insight on how to download the wordcloud2 output **(in any format)** from an app hosted on shiny.io will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53071531/shinyapps-io-publish-issue-webshot-dependent-library-phantomjs-missing/53161712#53161712) that I need to install phantom dependencies by adding the following code lines to the library call section

```
       webshot::install_phantomjs() 
       webshot:::find_phantom()
```

when publishing my app on shiny.io